# Access to extra fields by directly querying the intermediate model

Tags: django, model

i have the following problem:
I need to get the quantity of an ingredient for a recipe.

This is my models.py:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='RecipeHasIngredients')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeHasIngredients(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.recipe)
```

Answer (score 2):

there are two solutions:

1. Directly query `RecipeHasIngredients`:

   RecipeHasIngredients.objects.filter(recipe=recipe)
2. use through

   recipe_instance.ingredients.through.objects.all()

in both cases you get the a list of `RecipeHasIngredients` instances for given recipe

Comment: With your first solution I only get the name of the recipe, but I need the quantity.
With your second solution I get error: type object 'RecipeHasIngredients' has no attribute 'all'.
So how can I get access to the quantity of an ingredients?

Comment: first solution returns a list `print(type(value))` to be sure it's not string, also fixed second solution

Comment: Yes, I get the list of `RecipeHasIngredients`, but not the quantity.

Comment: I solved my problem by using: `RecipeHasIngredients.objects.filter(recipe=recipe).values_list('quantity', flat=True)`